# How to customize ssl handshake routine?

Tags: ssl, openssl, python-requests

Recently, I tried to access one special bizarre https server with python requests library and it always reported handshake_failure. However, I can access it with browser.

After some debugging with wireshark, I found the server refused the first clientHello directly. I knew there may be some bizarre behavior for that server.

What i ask is that how to customize ssl handshake routine to identify what exactly caused the server to refuse my clientHello?

For example, 
I want to add some extensions as the browser does during ssl handshake.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no easy customization with requests apart from ciphers and protocol version. Especially it is unlikely that you can add additional extensions. If you need full control use [scapy tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls). Still, in most cases you don't need such depth of customization and it is more likely that you have an old OpenSSL library (like still using OpenSSL 0.9.8 which has no support for TLS 1.2).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried scapy tls, but it failed to install. Finally I compiled the OpenSSL and found the reason. It seemed the server refused some cipher suites from the client which caused handshake failure. Thank you for information.